# Designing keywords in Clojure

Tags: design-patterns, clojure, keyword

I'm learning Clojure by developing a small web application.
Coming from Java world, I'm trying to understand how to design my data using keywords.

How should I access a data structure (model) fields?
For example, I have a `comment` with a `body` field.
I'm using the keyword `:body` to access the model value,
but it seems very difficult in the future if I would like to change the `body` name to something else (for example `content`).

As for Java, I would encapsulate it with a `get` function,
how should I use it in Cojure?
What are the design pattern or best practices?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a similar `get` function:

```
; Using bloated names here since 
;  get and comment are built-ins
(defn get-stuff [comment-node]
  (:body comment-node))
  ; ^ Update here!
```

Then you just need to change the keyword in that function.

Of course, an intelligent IDE might be able to do a proper refactor if you ever decide to change it too. I use IntelliJ + Cursive though, and they unfortunately aren't clever enough to pull off such a refactoring. I have to admit this is one thing that frustrates me about using keywords. They are far too "up in the air" for IDEs to be able to help out.

And whether or not you want a thin wrapper function like this depends on the use case. If it's a simple POD map, it may make sense to just use `(:x point)`. If it's a more complicated state, you may want to use a set of public API "methods" instead.

Comment: I also thought of doing this, it just seems not the clojure way. How so you do it in your projects? And I use cursive as well with idea

Answer (score 0):

Well, even in Java world, when you rename a field or a method in some class, not every IDE could refactor the thole project automatically. You'll definitely need to clean the code by hands.

Answering your question, try to choose proper names for the fields and do not change them in the future.

If you are still afraid of renaming issue, keep those functions that access sensitive field together in the same namespace.

Another advise could be, when you refer to some keyword to ofter, put it into local variable as shown below:

```
(let [field :comment
      value (get data field)
      value2 (get data2 field)]
  ...)
```

Keywords are quite powerful feature of Clojure when destructuring a map to the same-named variables, e.g:

```
(let [{:keys [comment body title]} node-data]
  ... now operate on those variables)
```

But even when you renamed any field, you may still access it with destructuring syntax as well. Imagine your data now has `:description` field instead of `:body`:

```
(let [{:keys [comment title] body :description} node-data]
  ... the body now points on the right field)
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLID principles aplies to Clojure programs as well. If your data can change then code against interface. By creating get method you will have to change only that method.

This might sound as a violation of "The Clojure Way" but in my humble opinion it is not. Having transparent data has its benefits for sure. At least you can pretty-print them in REPL. But if your data comes from a module which you do not have direct dependency on, it might not be worth creating an accidental dependency on its internal state.

I do not have Idea+Cursive because at work we develop Eclipse RCP apps. So I use Eclipse+Emacs+Cider and I can not speak about Cursive. Clj-refactor can not reliably refactor keywords in this case. You can use namespaced keywords which are easy to change just by find-replace. This is what I would use when I had data which can change over time but the change is unlikely and other parts of application could access it directly. Of course with unit tests and spec. If I had data which are likely to change (e.g. from external API) or other modules would have to access it via traversing deeply nested maps, I would create an interface (get method) in appropriate module.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** use something like clojure.set/rename or clojure.set/rename-keys.

**Harsh Advice**

It's my impression (mostly based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyLBGkS5ICk) that the "clojure way" is to think about your design thoroughly enough up-front that you're willing to stick with it. (c.f. "hammock-driven development").

If you do wind up needing to make this sort of change, create another set of functions (maybe use the same names in a different ns) that use the new keyword names. Now have these call your originals, or your originals call the new ones (whichever makes more sense). Update your docs to recommend that people use the new version.

Spend more time in the hammock.

**More generally** (and hopefully helpfully):

Try to keep your functions small and decoupled enough that you're just passing around a few values anyway. If you're calling something that needs a :body, how much of the rest of the associated values in that map does it really need?

Can you refactor those parts into their own functions to reduce the coupling? Can you supply/return higher-order functions to isolate functionality that seems like it needs to be all snarled up with your :content handling? (The "partial" function is your friend here).

**Full-blown explanation** (complete with personal whining):

These days, a big part of this involves using maps with namespaced keywords, along with spec. Since you can alias your namespaces, this actually seems to make the particular problem you're addressing worse: you can't even reliably do a simple search/replace over your project.

I'm going through a lot of pain in this regard right now, revisiting some code I wrote while I was figuring this out. I realized that I got the namespaces wrong.

If anyone else were actually using my library, the real answer would be to just accept that what I started with is ugly, broken, and poorly planned. I could write new functions that are more expressive than what I have now (so, in your example, they'd use a map that contains :bar/content rather than :foo/body). Maybe mark the old functions deprecated, but accept that I can never, ever eliminate them.

Or possibly I should just deprecate that library and point existing/potential users to a new one that more closely matches what I actually want.

Actually, it's enough of a mess that the latter option is tempting. Even though I'm the only user. Renaming keys like this seems almost deliberately painful.

Based on my experience with the rest of the language, I suspect that was the case, because breaking your API is a terrible thing to do.

**On the other hand**, there's at least one more piece to this.

What about black-box, undocumented data that you want to be able to change at the drop of a hat? (Say you have a value that you treat like a handle, which happens to be implemented as a map). The whole OOP private undocumented implementation details stuff.

This part of your API will have functions with names like "establish-database-connection!" and "run-database-command!". The rest of it really should be pure functions that set up sequences of pending side-effects that you pass to the ones that actually change the world.

The Pedestal library is a great example of this approach. Its context maps are pretty much the exact opposite of the approach I recommended above about just using as few decoupled values as possible for any given function call...these opinions are definitely and merely my own.

Your end-user is supposed to call your functions and get back...call it a gray box. They are responsible for supplying it (without modifications) to your other functions that rely on it (which, honestly, should be pretty rare: these are really for system-boundary code that causes side-effects). If they look inside, that's their business, but I think it's fair for you to change those details.

Changing those details under the hood takes us back to your original problem: doing so is still painful.

That's another reason to be very stingy about writing code that needs this sort of thing.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you're overthinking the problem. Most of the time I simply choose a name for a field in a map and just stick to it. Later on, it won't be very hard to find all the occurrences of your field and rename it using a simple search.
For me, the philosophy of Clojure is to make the code as simple and comprehensible as you can and don't think about too much flexibility upfront because Clojure itself is simple, flexible and dynamic so you can easily change the parts of your system later with minimal efforts.